# How to generate a Ractive <select> with only a max value

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

Using Ractive, I want to generate a dropdown with number options from 1 to n.

A select element can be generated using ([source](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/two-way-binding)):

```
<select value='{{selectedCountry}}'>
    <option selected disabled>Select a country</option>
    {{#countries}}
        <option value='{{id}}'>{{name}}</option>
    {{/countries}}
</select>
```

with:

```
ractive = new Ractive({
    el: myContainer,
    template: myTemplate,
    data: {
        countries: [
            { id: 'AFG', name: 'Afghanistan' },
            { id: 'ALB', name: 'Albania' },
            // and so on...
        ]
    }
});
```

So the data will change to something like:

```
ractive = new Ractive({
    el: myContainer,
    template: myTemplate,
    data: {
        n: 50
    }
});
```

But what is the syntax for the `#countries` loop when you only have a max value (`n`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select>
{{#each Array(n):i}}
    <option>option {{i}}</option>
{{/each}}
</select>
```

Relevant Docs:

- [Handlebars style sections](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/mustaches#handlebars-style-sections)
- [Adding array indexes](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/mustaches#array-index-references)
- use of `Array(n)` is calling the Array constructor function

Comment: @jcuenod added links